# Jquery Scroll between header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I'm trying to keep a div at the top of my page but, when I cross my point, I would like to stop scroll before another div..

```
<div class="my-top"><p>This is my top</p></div>
    <div class="big-one">
        <div class="mini1">
            <p>TEST 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mini2">
            <div id="mini-mini2">
                <p>Need to scroll</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-footer">
        <p>This is my footer</p>
    </div>
```

Here is a fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/2q773opz/3/

When I scroll, my div go down but she can stop at the end of "mini2", she goes back to his top :(
What did I miss? Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Your code seems to work fine - the element pins to the top as you scroll passed it. What's the issue you have?

Comment: Thank for you reply Rory. I would like to stop scrolling at the end of "mini2"..

Comment: In fact, i want to scroll between "top" and "footer" but, when i scoll down, i want to fix it at the bottom (not over "footer")..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `#mini-mini2`'s parent to be `position:relative` you can position `#mini-mini2` absolutely *within* it. Then simply have your JS set the element's position `top` to be the current `scrollTop` minus the header height (use similar logic to prevent the `#mini-mini2` from being pushed too far.

It's basic, but as a proof of concept see this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var breaking = $('.big-one').offset().top;
    var limit = $('.my-footer').offset().top - $('#mini-mini2').height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var top = scrolltop - breaking;
        if (scrolltop > breaking && scrolltop < limit) {
            $('#mini-mini2').css("top", top);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.my-top,
.my-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height;
    50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.my-top {
    height: 250px;
}

.my-footer {
    height: 450px;
}

.big-one {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.mini1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 74%;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 250px;
}

.mini2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}

#mini-mini2 {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}


/*.big-one div.floatable {position:fixed;top:2px;}*/

#mini-mini2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-top">
    <p>
        This is my top
    </p>
</div>
<div class="big-one">
    <div class="mini1">
        <p>
            TEST 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mini2">
        <div id="mini-mini2">
            <p>
                Need to scroll
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-footer">
    <p>
        This is my footer
    </p>
</div>
```

Also: [Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q773opz/17/)

---

**UPDATE**

Whilst the above version works it's possible to miss-position `#mini-mini2` if you scroll too quickly. To combat this it's probably better to toggle the elements `position:fixed` and `top` vs `bottom` in order to get it to sit just right like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var breaking = $('.big-one').offset().top;
    var limit = $('.my-footer').offset().top - $('#mini-mini2').height();

    $('#mini-mini2').css("width",$('.mini2').width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
     $('#mini-mini2').css("width",$('.mini2').width());
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var top = scrolltop - breaking;
        if (scrolltop > breaking && scrolltop < limit) {
            $('#mini-mini2').addClass("fixed");
         $('#mini-mini2').css("bottom", "auto");
            $('#mini-mini2').css("top", 0);
        } else if(scrolltop > breaking) {
         $('#mini-mini2').removeClass("fixed");
         $('#mini-mini2').css("bottom", 0);
            $('#mini-mini2').css("top", "auto");
        } else {
         $('#mini-mini2').removeClass("fixed");
         $('#mini-mini2').css("bottom", "auto");
            $('#mini-mini2').css("top", 0);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.my-top,
.my-footer {
    width: 100%;
    height;
    50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.my-top {
    height: 250px;
}

.my-footer {
    height: 450px;
}

.big-one {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.mini1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 74%;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 250px;
}

.mini2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}

#mini-mini2 {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}


/*.big-one div.floatable {position:fixed;top:2px;}*/

#mini-mini2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

}
#mini-mini2.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-top">
    <p>
        This is my top
    </p>
</div>
<div class="big-one">
    <div class="mini1">
        <p>
            TEST 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mini2">
        <div id="mini-mini2">
            <p>
                Need to scroll
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-footer">
    <p>
        This is my footer
    </p>
</div>
```

Also: [Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q773opz/19/)

Comment: Thanks, you roxxxxx ! :)

Answer (score 0):

To limit the lower scroll you need to put the remove the class when the `scrollTop()` of the window is higher than the top of the `.my-footer` element, minus the height of the `#mini-mini2` element. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $mini = $('#mini-mini2');
    var toggle = $(window).scrollTop() >= breaking && $(window).scrollTop() <= (limit - $mini.height());
    $mini.toggleClass("floatable", toggle);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2q773opz/15/)

Comment: Is it possible to stop #mini-mini2 at the bottom of "mini2" ? With your code, she goes back to the top and i would like to stop her at the bottom.